# How can I attend a contest and go to the airport on the same day?

Tags: personal-care

**Note**: *This is my first question here; I logged in just a few seconds ago. My question is not exactly on-topic, but I don't know any other SE site appropriate for this. This site is the closest to my nature of problem. Before you go on to downvote this, stop and think. Do you happen to know just the right SE site for this question? If so, feel free to delete this note and migrate it to that site. If not, close it or find an alternate solution.*

I live in Bangladesh. A nation-wide programming contest is going to be held on 24th March. The contest is vitally important for me, and I must participate.

However, my grandparents have their flight on the very same day. Me and my family have to leave them off at the airport and bid them farewell.

I don't really prioritise this over the contest, but I'm more or less forced to. I'm only 13 and can't stay at my house alone, while the rest of my family will be gone outside for hours. Also, I need an adult to take me to the contest.

Again, I really want to see my grandparents before they fly off to the US. And it'll be quite some time before they come back to Bangladesh. Even though the contest will be on next year, participating this year is very important for me for reasons not worth explaining right now.

> Is there any way I can avoid going to the airport and attend the
>   contest instead?

Comment: from the title I assumed you meant you wanted to attend a contest and a funeral!

Comment: Lol! I'm editing the title.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to put this in the answer space even though a) it's not the answer you want & b) the question is off-topic, but also because there is no SE site that will fix this.

You're 13; at 13 life sucks because you want to do one thing but you have to do another. You're not in charge & you won't be for many years.

Your programming contest will be on again next year. If it isn't, it wasn't that good a contest. You'll be better next year anyway.

Your grandparents won't be around forever. You'll miss them when they aren't.

In the meantime, you have to go to the airport; you have no choice.
You have to wave goodbye to your grandparents. They'll remember that even if you forget.

Whilst you're doing this - all of it, not just the last 2 minutes - you leave your phone in your pocket & your laptop at home. They will never know what you think you sacrificed to see them off, but they will remember the happy child that waved to them as they left.

They would also remember the sullen teen who didn't want to be there, wouldn't say a word & couldn't get their phone away from their face for long enough to even say, "Bye."

Which one of those images to you want to be? Forever.

Comment: I know, I really want to see my grandparents before they fly off to the US. And it'll be quite some time before they come back to Bangladesh, the country I'm living in. But, even though the contest will be next year, participating this year is very important for me for reasons not worth explaining right now.